# Keep elements from collapsing in on each other when page shrinks

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently anytime you shrink the page, my elements end up moving on top of each other instead of just causing the page to scroll.. can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Div Blocks</title>

<style type="text/css">
html {
        background: url(bgo.jpg) no-repeat center center ;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
position:relative;


}

    a{
    cursor : url("nav.png"), pointer;
    }

  div.one a
{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:60px;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("branding.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:35px;
}
div.one a:hover
{background: url("brandingalt.png");
 background-position: 0px 0px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.two a
{
position: absolute;
top:264px;
left:60px;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("marketing.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:35px;
}
div.two a:hover
 {background: url("marketingalt.png");
 background-position:0px 0px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
div.three a
{
position: absolute;
top:457px;
left:56px;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("ecommerce.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:20px;
}
div.three a:hover
 {background: url("ecommercealt.png");
background-position: 0 0px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.r1 a
{
position: absolute;
top:50px;
right:60px;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("webdesign.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:25px;
}
div.r1 a:hover
 {background: url("webdesignalt.png");
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

div.r2 a
{
position: absolute;
top:254px;
right:75px;
width: 450px;
height: 150px;
text-decoration:none;
background:url("optimization.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-bottom:20px;
}
div.r2 a:hover
 {background: url("optimizationalt.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.r3 a
{
position: absolute;
top:457px;
right:60px;
width: 400px;
height: 75px;
text-decoration:none;
padding-bottom: 20px;
background:url(packaging.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
div.r3 a:hover
 {background: url("packagingalt.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>



    <div class="one">
<a href="#" value="Branding" class="go" ></a>
    </div>

    <div class="two">
<a href="#" class="go"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div>

    <div class="r1">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div>
      <div class="r2">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div>

            <div class="r3">
<a href="#"class="go" ></a>
    </div>




    </body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the link from changing the location
    $(this)
        .closest("div") // select the parent div of the link

        .siblings() // select all the siblings of the div
        .hide("slow") // hide them
setTimeout(function() {

$(".go").animate({top: "0"}, "slow");},1200);

});




</script>
```

Ive tried floating the elements, using the table trick, using overflow, and yet i cant seem to get it to work properly.

Comment: I am not going to answer this, because I am a little unsure, but you are using `position: absolute;` for all these divs, so when you shrink the page, the size of the canvas changes.  Some are positioned from the left, a few from the right.  If you positioned everything from the left, it should work...

Comment: Do you have a screenshot?  You didn't publish the graphics so it is hard to reproduce.

I tried to reproduce your page here, but it is hard to figure out what you want to do.  http://jsfiddle.net/RQ8QA/

Comment: positioning everything from the left worked great, thanks a lot tim!

Answer (score 0):

Using `position: absolute;` removes the elements from the flow of the page so they will not 'run into' each other. Instead, if you can figure out how to do it without that, you will get the desired effect. You can also set a `min-width` on the page, but it will not cause vertical scroll but horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say but it seems that you have issues with your absolute positioning...

Look at this page  http://jsfiddle.net/RQ8QA/1/

Notice that I changed everything from position:absolute to position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution as far as I can see would be to wrap all of your elements in a fixed-width container, which will not resize when the browser is shrank.

If you're trying to keep a variable-width, a solution I've found myself using quite a lot recently has been to make all of your elements inline (or inline-block), place them next to each other, and then add `white-space: nowrap` to their container.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="elem-1">
        ...
    </div><div class="elem-2">
        ...
    </div><div class="elem-3">
        ...
    </div><div class="elem-4">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note that the succeeding elements are touching: `</div><div class="elem`. This is not a typo; removing the space in your markup this keeps your inline elements touching when they are displayed.*

CSS:

```
#container { white-space: nowrap; }
#container > div { 
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block; }
```

*Note that you need to set `white-space: normal` in each of your inner elements if you want them to behave normally.*